# Android Studio won't start M1 Mac

Tags: android-studio, apple-m1, android-studio-arctic-fox

The emulator works fine when I use it through VS Code, but I can't seem to open Android Studio. Version: Arctic Fox (2020.3.1)[image: Error message]

Comment: I'd try running it on a different version of Java if you have one. Else you probably need to report this as a bug on the link at the top.

Comment: Yeah that didn't really work, I'll try to clean install once or install a different version